# has_one association and nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-one

I have a model `Post`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :draft, class_name: Post, foreign_key: draft_id
end
```

In `routes.rb` I have the following:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts do
    resource :draft
  end
end
```

What I want to achieve is to enable drafts when using `form_for`, i.e.:

```
= form_for [:admin, @post, @draft] do |form|
```

...where `@post` and `@draft` are different instances of the same model.

Right now if I do that, I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `admin_tour_tour_url'
```

**Question**: So how do I make the form generate `admin_tour_draft_url` + with a needed modifiers like `edit_` and `new_`?

P.S. am I going the wrong path here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify your own path in the form_tag helper by extracting the route explicitly from your routes:

1) rake routes | grep admin_posts

2) notice the path.. probably something like 'admin_posts_draft'

3) add '_path' to the path and that is the name of your helper.. use that helper in your code

```
<%= form_tag admin_posts_draft_path(@post, @draft) %>
<% end %>
```